# Updating value in array object

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update the value of an object in an array of my mongodb schema using mongoose and nodejs.

My model is :

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("557eecd687cff9281040efe5"),
"products": [
    {
        "productId": "6849500",
        "qty": 2,
        "_id": ObjectId("557eef13101aef4c101af513")
    }
]
}
```

I would like to update the "products" array "qty" value filtering on "productId"

Comment: Hint: `{$set:{'products.$.qty':'qty_value '}.`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following update which uses the **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** to identify an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array. Since the positional **[`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document, the array field must appear as part of the query document hence you need the `products` array field in your query:

```
db.collection.update(
    {"products._id": ObjectId("557eef13101aef4c101af513")}, 
    {"$set": {"products.$.qty": 8} }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the operator `$`.

```
ModelName.update({
  //find the document
},{
  products.$.qty : //value
});
```

**ALITER**

Maybe you will have to make a new object

```
{
    "productId": "6849500",
    "qty": //some new value,
    "_id": ObjectId("557eef13101aef4c101af513")
}
```

and then update the document,

I personally think that the second approach will be more safe and sound.

Comment: Okay. I guess nested `$` are not supported. Thanks i will update my answer!